# Serilog does not log to Console in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I created a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application and added these Nuget packages:

```
Serilog.AspNetCore 2.1.1
Serilog.Settings.Configuration 2.6.1
Serilog.Sinks.Console 3.1.1
```

`Program.cs` looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console());
}
```

This is the `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyApplication"
    }
  }
}
```

I added a Controller which looks like this:

```
public class HelloController : Controller
{
    // GET
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Log.Debug("Test");
        return new OkObjectResult("Hello world");
    }
}
```

While the `HelloController` itself works as expected, I don't see the `Test` Debug output from the console.

This is the console log output after calling the Controller:

```
[21:39:16 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" started.
[21:39:16 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" started.
[21:39:16 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/hello
[21:39:16 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/hello
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" completed keep alive response.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" completed keep alive response.
[21:39:17 INF] Request finished in 80.8969ms 200
[21:39:17 INF] Request finished in 80.8969ms 200
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" received FIN.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" received FIN.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" disconnecting.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" disconnecting.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" sending FIN.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" sending FIN.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" stopped.
[21:39:17 DBG] Connection id "0HLEJO3CE6S7J" stopped.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

It was not my Controller returning "Hello world" but this line in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.Run(async (context) => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!"); });
```

Comment: can you see your Serilog logs in debug?(with out adding the sink)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a couple of improvements:

1. Don't duplicate the sinks configuration, there is no need to configure the same sinks both in code and in appsettings. Choose one and go with it.
2. ASP .NET Core is built to support dependency injection. Inject `ILogger<HelloController>` in `HelloController` instead of accessing the static `Log.Debug`.
3. Kudos to you for finding the problem and reporting it in your question, it will surely help other developers.

For a very small example of Serilog and ASP .NET Core 2.1, take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-dotnet-core).